# include tables, include pdfs, caption problem

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I have three pdf document (each of which contain a table) I want to include these pdfs  and add a final title (one caption for all of them) 
it was done but there is  a huge space between the last table see figure [image: figure] ( pdf that include this table) and title (caption I tried `\vspace*{-0.5cm}` it does not work for me help please. here is my pdfs [pdfs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_6RXQUqktUOemgtcEJvUjBzcWM?usp=sharing) how to fix this

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
  \begin{document}
  \newpage
  \begin{table}
 \includegraphics [width=.99\linewidth, height=.99\textheight]{111.pdf}

\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{table}
\includegraphics [width=.99\linewidth, height=.99\textheight]{222.pdf}
\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{table}
\includegraphics [width=.99\linewidth, height=.99\textheight]{333.pdf}
\centering
\vspace*{-0.5cm}
\caption{recap}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to properly crop the original PDF before including it. BTW, the last `333pdf` is missing a dot.

Comment: yeah I forgot it when but it is okey on my project  what do you mean by "crop the original PDF before including it." how to  this ! please

Comment: You have large white space after the third table, you need to use a tool like Acrobat Professional, Inkscape, etc. to crop it (easier), or crop it when including in LaTeX (harder).

Comment: `\begin{document}` is missing@mirette

Comment: yeah Biki I forget it when am coping my example, Soory @AboAmmar  "to crop it (easier), or crop it when including in LaTeX (harder). " how is that I dont know :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to properly crop the original PDF before including it. Specifically,  there is large white space after the third table. The LaTeX solution for this is to use the `crop` and `trim` options when including the PDF.

Sometimes, cropping is not easy, so we temporarily add `\fbox{..}` around the figure to visualize how much we crop. The syntax for `trim` is `trim = left bottom right top`. After properly cropping the figure, just remove that `\fbox{..}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 

\newpage
\begin{table}
\includegraphics [width=.99\linewidth, height=.99\textheight]{111.pdf}

\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{table}
\includegraphics [width=.99\linewidth, height=.99\textheight]{222.pdf}
\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{table}
\fbox{\includegraphics[clip, trim=1.0cm 20cm 0.0cm 2cm, width=.99\linewidth]{333.pdf}}
\centering
\caption{recap}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: dear Ammar thank you a lot :) am really gratefull just one question can I deleate the new added frame since the 222.pdf and 111.pdf are not framed!! which instruction is responsible for !! and thank you :)

Comment: @mirette -- Yes, remove that `\fbox{..}` when finished clipping your figure.

Comment: awsome! thank you Ammar :) am defenitely gratefull :)

Comment: just one question how to make (the style as in my latex project it is very clear that is an imported document I would like to use same style where find this information !!please could it be fixed !! ( honestly I could not  do the tables on latex like on word one table .... I  tried to import a pdf but you see have not same style could this be fixed

Comment: @mirette - Your tables are not complicated, they are only big,  but can be easily converted into LaTeX. You can use an [online table generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables#) to speed up this. Sure, feel free to open new questions if you need help converting these.

Comment: another question soory :| for the online generator I have an excel file including my table could this be automatically converted !! ( am soory too many questions but need really help and guidance! )